# Energy conservation for the beam splitter from first principles

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Let's consider a (cubic) beam splitter with two electric input fields $E_1,E_2$ and two electric output fields $E_3,E_4$ as illustrated in the figure below.

[image: Beam splitter schematic from Wikipedia]

For a lossless beam splitter, we almost always find the literature claim
$$
\vert\boldsymbol{E}_1\vert^2+\vert\boldsymbol{E}_2\vert^2
=
\vert\boldsymbol{E}_3\vert^2+\vert\boldsymbol{E}_4\vert^2
\tag{1}
$$
which intuitively matches our idea of a lossless beam splitter.

However, assume we don't take eq. (1) for granted are highly skeptical of our intuition. **How can we derive eq. (1) from first principles?**

#### Strategy A: energy density

In strategy A, we take the definition of the electromagnetic field's energy density,
$$
u
=
\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\boldsymbol{E}^2+\frac{\epsilon_0c^2}{2}\boldsymbol{B}^2
\tag{2},
$$
for granted.
Using $c^2\boldsymbol{B}^2=\boldsymbol{E}^2$ for the free field solutions of Maxwell's equations, the energy density becomes
$$
u=\epsilon_0\boldsymbol{E}^2
\tag{3}.
$$
So far, so good, the total energy of the field is obtained by integrating over the total volume,
$$
H
=
\int dV\ u
=
\epsilon_0\int dV\ \boldsymbol{E}^2
\tag{4}.
$$
However, eq. (4) is only valid for a single field. I feel uncomfortable to state
$$
H_1+H_2
=
H_3+H_4
\tag{5}
$$
as we do not know what happens in the beam splitter volume (so far, the beam splitter is a black box).

#### Strategy B: energy flux

Because of the afore problem, I tried another approach that uses the energy flux (or Poynting vector)
$$
\boldsymbol{S}
=
\epsilon_0c^2\boldsymbol{E}\times\boldsymbol{B}
\tag{6}.
$$
For freely propagating light, we can use $c\boldsymbol{B}=\boldsymbol{e}_k\times\boldsymbol{E}$ wherein $\boldsymbol{e}_k$ is the unit vector pointing in the direction of propagation. We then find
$$
\boldsymbol{S}
=
\epsilon_0c\boldsymbol{E}^2\boldsymbol{e}_k
\tag{7}
$$
to be the energy flux of a single electromagnetic wave propagating in the direction of $\boldsymbol{e}_k$.

Now, let's define the $x$ axis to point in the direction of $\boldsymbol{E}_1$ and the $y$ axis to point in parallel w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{E}_2$.
Furthermore, we say that the energy flux at the deflection point in the center of the beam splitter has to vanish, i.e.,
$$
\boldsymbol{S}_1+\boldsymbol{S}_2+\boldsymbol{S}_3+\boldsymbol{S}_4=0
\tag{8}.
$$
Obviously, eq. (8) cannot be true because $\boldsymbol{S}_2$ and $\boldsymbol{S}_4$ are orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{S}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{S}_3$ and this would lead to $\boldsymbol{E}_1^2=\boldsymbol{E}_3^2$ and $\boldsymbol{E}_2^2=\boldsymbol{E}_4^2$.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

Energy is not a vector. So leaning on the Poynting vector in that way can lead you down a confusing path. There are two ways you could remedy this:

1. Treat the Poynting vector (divided by the speed of light) as the vector *momentum flux* (and don’t forget the force on the beamsplitter!).
2. Equate the *absolute value* of the energy fluxes into the beamsplitter to be zero. Because the beamsplitter is lossless.

Option 2 seems simpler, but by then it’s such a short step to what you want to prove that it’s basically a tautology.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first option? Am I correct that you want to impose momentum conservation on the incident and output beams including the beam splitter?